# How do I remove extra space after Label/Div

Tags: html

I have two Text fields that I want to line up underneath each other. I put a spacer `div` in front with the width of 2em and a background color just to be able to see how big the spacer is during testing. One of them needs to have a `label` in front, which I put inside the spacer `div` so the text field with and without the `label` will still have the same space in front of each other.

Now the problem is that it always adds a little space, like a blank space, between the `label` and the text field. It doesn't do it for the text field without the `label`.

The space wasn't there once I removed the spacer `div`, but without it I don't know how to keep the space in front of the two text fields matched. I tried putting the same `style` from the spacer `div` in the `label`, but then the space reappears.

I also tried various ways to remove `padding` or `margin` all without success. I even tried adding `&nbsp` in front of the `div` at the second text field to add the space, but then that space was a little bit bigger than the one from the `label`.

This is the HTML generated when I open the sourcecode in Chrome. You won't be able to see the extra space here, which is frustrating, but it's there on my website.

```html
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="width:2em; height: 1em;background-color:mediumvioletred; float:left;"><label for="veranstaltungsnamea">a)</label></div>
        <input type="text" name="veranstaltungsnamea" id="veranstaltungsnamea" value="k" 
        onchange="veranstaltungteilprüfung('a')" placeholder="deutsch" style="width:90%; margin-left:6;" >
       </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div style="width:2em; height: 1em;background-color:mediumvioletred; float:left;"></div>
        <input type="text" name="veranstaltungsnameengla" id="veranstaltungsnameengla" placeholder="englisch" value="l" 
        style="width:90%;">
                </div>
    </div>
```

Preview from my website:
[image: Preview from my website]

In my PHP the code looks like this.

```
echo '
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div style="width:2em; height: 1em;background-color:mediumvioletred; float:left;"><label for="veranstaltungsname' . $id . '">'. $id . ')</label></div>
                <input type="text" name="veranstaltungsname' . $id . '" id="veranstaltungsname' . $id . '" value="';

        echo findValue('veranstaltungsname' . $id, $sheetData);

        echo '" 
                onchange="veranstaltungteilprüfung(\'' . $id . '\')" placeholder="deutsch" style="width:90%; margin-left:6;" >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div style="width:2em; height: 1em;background-color:mediumvioletred; float:left;"></div>
                <input type="text" name="veranstaltungsnameengl' . $id . '" id="veranstaltungsnameengl' . $id . '" placeholder="englisch" value="';

        echo findValue('veranstaltungsnameengl' . $id, $sheetData);

        echo '" 
                style="width:90%;">
            </div>
        </div>';
```

Comment: Running your snippet seems to be working just right...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Like I mentioned in my question, the extra space doesn't show up in the snippet, but it does on my website.

Comment: Check below answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an issue in firefox, i updated your code it is working fine now.
The problem was `margin` to input, make it `margin:0` to input it will give you results.

```html
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="width:2em; height: 1em;background-color:mediumvioletred; float:left;"><label for="veranstaltungsnamea">a)</label></div>
        <input type="text" name="veranstaltungsnamea" id="veranstaltungsnamea" value="k" 
        onchange="veranstaltungteilprüfung('a')" placeholder="deutsch" style="width:90%; margin:0px;" >
       </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div style="width:2em; height: 1em;background-color:mediumvioletred; float:left;"></div>
        <input type="text" name="veranstaltungsnameengla" id="veranstaltungsnameengla" placeholder="englisch" value="l" 
        style="width:90%; margin:0px">
                </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: May i know the reason to dislike answer ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't even consider checking/changing the `margin` on the text field itself! Thank you, that was absolutely the issue and immediately fixed it. You're a godsent.